# How to query Many to Many with Amplify Graphql

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I have 3 tables: User, Post and Comment:

[image]

One user has comments in many posts and one post has many users that write comment. I want to make a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Comment 
     JOIN User ON Comment.userId = User.id 
     JOIN Post ON Comment.postId = Post.id
WHERE User.gender = 'MALE' AND Post.title LIKE "%some word%"
```

How can I do that with amplify graphql?

Comment: Do let us know if you have found the answer.

Comment: No, i haven't =(((. I'm waiting for answers

Comment: Please copy the code into your question instead of using an image.